# Open multiple windows in Firefox with a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to open 2 firefox windows with a batch file.

for example, this code:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

only starts one window, but I want 2 of them, any sugestion :)?

Thanks

Comment: I won't work, it says the task is already running

Comment: Googled the question title, found a solution, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wonder if the code the questioner is looking for is for annoying some one with on their machine... lol

Comment: Amazing.  The first link Google finds is the answer to your question.

Comment: No it's not !!!! ffs I tried everything and it didn't work ffs!

Comment: @Squashman don't acuse me lol try first for yourself lol, toxic people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this line twice

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -new-instance
```

Comment: @StackFlowed - I don't know where you got that idea, because this absolutely works, and is the correct answer.

Comment: @SomethingDark check the duplicate question answer. Well this would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't acuse me that I didn't googled, cuz I did, try for yourselves the googles solutions, It's possible to open TABS, but windows, I couldn't

Answer (score -1):

Maybe i think to simple, but you could try using the `Start` command twice.

`start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" 
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"`

And if you want to open two tabs try this:
`start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" www.mozilla.com developer.mozilla.org`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options

Comment: This will depend on the user preference how to open the external links, and usually it's "new tab". Also this was already rejected in the comments. On the other hand both the duplicate question that I've linked and the documentation contain an actually correct command line switch.